# .NET remoting - nested MarshalByRefObject

Tags: .net, remoting, marshalbyrefobject

I am using the deprecated .NET remoting for purposes that otherwise are not possible to accomplish by WCF. I have a situation in which I use a `MarshalByRefObject` but one that has nested `MarshalByRefObject`s that are not exposed as properties but used internally.

I am using the ClientSponsor on the client side to manage the lifetime of those objects. Does registering needs to be done on all nested `MarshalByRefObject`s or is it sufficent to do it on the root `MarshalByRef` "visible" (it is indeed an interface so there is no DLL sharing) to the client?

Thank you in advance